# AngularJS: ngModel $formatters gives undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, formatter, angularjs-ng-model

Here is an example of phone formatter I designed:

```
(function () {
  /* @ngInject */
  function MyPhoneDirective($filter) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: 'ngModel',
      link(scope, element, attributes, ngModel) {
        ngModel.$parsers.push((modelValue) => {
          modelValue = modelValue.replace(' ', '');
          ngModel.$modelValue = modelValue;

          return modelValue;
        });

        ngModel.$formatters.push((viewValue) => {
          console.log(viewValue); // gives undefined
          viewValue = $filter('phoneFormatter')(viewValue);
          ngModel.$viewValue = viewValue;

          return viewValue;
        });
      },
    };
  }

  angular
    .module('module.common')
    .directive('myPhone', MyPhoneDirective);
}());
```

And here is a usage example

```
<input type="text" ng-model="phoneNumber" my-phone />
```

But is does not work, `viewValue` is always undefined. Any ideas, please?

Comment: try `angular.module('module.common',[ ])`

Comment: @RameshRajendran I already have that module defined other place

Comment: Then you should inject this module to the main module.

Comment: And this is also done, `$parsers` work well though

Comment: can you try like this https://jsfiddle.net/pj32dsqv/29/ it works for me tough .

Comment: @supercool I see, can't get what's wrong with my app

Comment: set your $scope variable 'phoneNumber' with some value